# Grails, groovy: combine GORM dynamic methods - findAllBy and OrderBy

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

assuming the following example:
I have a User class and a Item class and a user can have many items

1) Is there a combined dynamic method to get all the items for a user and also sort them after a Property? I have a controller action that gets the items for a user and send them to the view, and the view will render them all with < g:each>. But I want to sort them by any property of Item without sorting the array **after** it is relived from GORM (using *sort* in controller or view).
So basically what I do now is

```
items = Item.findAllByOwner(userInstance)
```

and then send the [items:items.sort{it.property}] to the view. I want to combine *findAllBy* with

```
Item.listOrderByProperty()
```

2) Assuming that there is such a method as on 1) : I want to use it to escape the overhead of sorting the array after constructing it. Will such a method be more performant instead of making a sort{} on items ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a map of options to findAllBy. Take a look at http://www.grails.org/doc/1.2.2/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html .

Comment: Yeah, I just found that. It now looks like a stupid question - but thanks for the good answer.